# Detect and removing JSONArray null response

Tags: android, json

I am getting json response as

```
   {"image_data": [
[
  {
    "post_id": "331",
    "meta_key": "_wp_attached_file",
    "meta_value": "2014/09/443025.jpg"
  }
],
[
  {
    "post_id": "364",
    "meta_key": "_wp_attached_file",
    "meta_value": "2014/09/632026.jpg"
  }
],
[
  {
    "post_id": "657",
    "meta_key": "_wp_attached_file",
    "meta_value": "2014/10/233506.jpg"
  }
],
[
  {
    "post_id": "727",
    "meta_key": "_wp_attached_file",
    "meta_value": "2014/10/653413.jpg"
  }
],
"null",
"null",
[
  {
    "post_id": "958",
    "meta_key": "_wp_attached_file",
    "meta_value": "2014/10/801582.jpg"
  }
   ]
  ]
  }
```

Problem is am getting error for type mismatch because of null value. In given json response there is three null value. I have to detect that null value and ignore that value. I've tried

```
  JSONArray imageDataArray = response.getJSONArray("image_data");
  for (int j = 0; j < imageDataArray.length(); j++) {
                                // ad image data
                                if ((imageDataArray.getJSONArray(j)) == null) {
                                    continue;
                                }else{
                                    JSONArray adimageData = imageDataArray
                                            .getJSONArray(j);

                                     //doing my work
                                }

                            }
```

But getting type mismatch error. In logcat it saying value null can not be converted to jsonarray. I need solution ...... please suggest me to do the right thing

Comment: why not try using a "proper" json library like Jackson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you would make json data consistent.
If you modify your string json removing "null", your json data will be consistent.
Below an example with your data and it works correctly.
I have used org.json.simple library.

```
 jsdata = jsdata.replace("\"null\",","");



    try {
        JSONObject  jso = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(jsdata);

        JSONArray jsArray = (JSONArray) jso.get("image_data");

        //Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = jsArray.iterator();
        Iterator<JSONArray> iterator = jsArray.iterator();


        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
           JSONArray a2 = iterator.next();
            Iterator<JSONObject> i2 = a2.iterator();

            while(i2.hasNext()){
                JSONObject itemObj = i2.next();
                String s = (String) itemObj.get("post_id");

                Log.i("MYTAG",s);
            }



       }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
if ((imageDataArray.getJSONArray(j)) == null) {
```

to

```
if ((imageDataArray.isNull(j))) {
```

That will check the JSONArray to see if your index is null, so you don't have to use `getJSONArray(index)` which causes the error.

Comment: Thnx for reply. but getting the error in 
JSONArray adimageData = imageDataArray         .getJSONArray(j); 

this line.

Answer (score 0):

Would you need to convert it to a JSON array. Couldn't you just check

```
if(imageDataArray.get(i) == null)
```

or
    if(imageDataArray.get(i) == "null")

Source: [http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html][1]